# How to get the containing WebDataGrid (Infragistics NetAdvantage) control from a row in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, infragistics, netadvantage

When a row has been selected, I am successfully getting selected row:

```
var currentRow = sender.get_behaviors().get_selection().get_selectedRowsResolved()[0];
```

Is there a javascript function to get the parent WebDataGrid for that row?
Something like this:

```
var grid = currentRow.get_parentGrid();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, its very simple:

```
currentRow.get_grid()
```

It gives you the parent grid.

Thanks Everyone!

Answer (score 2):

With:

```
var grid = currentRow.get_parentGrid();
```

you will access the parent row object, but to access the parent grid you need to call:

```
var grid = currentRow.get_parentGrid().get_grid();
```